# Android: Date is not being displayed as local time

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I am trying to retrieve a `date` from a `sqlite` database and display it in a text view. In spite of using **TimeZone.getDefault()**, the time still shows up as GMT time, not the local time.

Here is the method where I try to convert the date to local time:

```
public String formatDate(String stringDate) {
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date = sdf.parse(stringDate);
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        sdf.setTimeZone(tz);
        Log.v("formatDate", "TimeZone   " + tz.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT) + " Timezon id :: " + tz.getID());
        return sdf.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return stringDate;
}
```

As you can see, I wanted to see if the timezone *is* actually the local time or not and added a log statement for that. Here is the output for the log statement:

```
02-25 15:15:55.422 29855-29855/com.example.ishita.assigntasks V/formatDate: TimeZone   GMT+05:30 Timezon id :: Asia/Calcutta
```

And here is the line where I call `formatDate()`:

```
viewHolder.timeStamp.setText(formatDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(TasksContract.MessageEntry.COL_AT))));
```

Please point out where I am going wrong and what I can do to display the date/time in the time zone where the device is being used.

Comment: Could you add sample input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are not converting anything, because `SimpleDateFormat` use by default the default time zone, so you are parsing and formating the date with the same time zone. What happens if you set the timezone to UTC *before parsing* the date (then back to default before formatting) ? :

```
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

    // convert from UTC
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    try {
```